# Workflow developing tools for liferay 6

Tags: java, workflow, liferay

I am working with eclipse indigo for creating liferay portlets.Now I want to create a custom workflow.How can I get the plug-in or IDE for the same ? How can i create custom workflow with Kaleo.

Help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware the Liferay only provides a Kaleo plugin with Liferay Developer Studio, for which you need an enterprise License.

It's one of the bonuses of going Enterprise with Liferay. There maybe other plugins out there, but I don't know of any.

Comment: Liferay Kaleo plugin also comes with the community edition ( i.e. Liferay CE). You can get it in the Liferay Marketplace